# How can I run a batch file with a loop as a scheduled task?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in a batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (%CD%\clients.txt) do (
    start "My Task" /d "%CD%" /b php -f "%CD%\task.php" "%%a" "/%%b"
)
```

If I run the batch file manually from the command prompt, it works fine. However, if I run it as a scheduled task it fails and Last Run Result displays (0x2). Note that if I remove the loop from the code and hardcode values for the variables in the process to be run, the task runs fine.

I've also noticed that any kind of simple file operation, such as echo test > log.txt doesn't seem to run when the batch file is executed by the scheduled task, but works manually. I tried setting the scheduled task to "Run with highest privileges", doesn't fix it. I also set the "Start in" setting for the scheduled task action to the directory where the PHP and text files are, that doesn't work either. Am running out of ideas here, any thoughts?

Comment: If I had to guess, `%CD%` is not what you think it is (it refers to the *current directory*, which is not necessarily the directory that the batch script is in).

Comment: Thanks! That put me on the right track and I figured it out. Solution posted in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. As iCodez pointed out in the comments, %CD% was not what I expected it to be. Files were getting created in my simple tests, but in the wrong folder. The problem was caused by the fact that I had updated HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun to point to a different folder. Looks like this was taking precedence over the Start In directory I was specifying in the scheduled task. I removed my AutoRun key and things started working property. Just goes to show it's risky to edit some of those registry keys!

Comment: You can use `cmd /d /c myBatchFile.cmd` to avoid execution of the autorun registry entries